# Delphi/Rdp check username and password before connect

Tags: delphi, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

as the subject say am trying to connect to server using this code in delphi

```
procedure TmainF.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
   rdp1 : TMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting ;
begin
  rdp1 := TMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting.Create(self);
  rdp1.Parent := mainF;
  rdp1.Server:=server_name;
  rdp1.UserName := user.Text;
  rdp1.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword := password.Text;
  rdp1.ConnectingText := 'connecting';
  rdp1.DisconnectedText := 'disconnected';
  rdp1.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel:=0;
  rdp1.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport:=true;
  rdp1.Connect;
end;
```

the code is working fine but if the user entered a wrong user name or password
the rdp object is showing the remote desktop login prompt box to reenter the user name or password like the image

[image]

I want to validate the username and password before connect
or prevent this box and show a custom message from my app

I tried to use OnLogonError() procedure but it's not fired any code
and I read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669589/prevent-failed-logon-attempt-window-after-failing-to-supply-proper-credentials-t) but the code is c# and I confused with .getocx() and I can't find (PromptForCredentials) in (MSTSCLib_TLB.pas)

any help :( ??

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interface `IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5` that has the following methods:

- `Get_AllowPromptingForCredentials()`
- `Set_AllowPromptingForCredentials()`

If you call `Set_AllowPromptingForCredentials()` with the parameter set to `false` the dialog won't appear.

As for how to get an instance of this interface - easy, you just cast the `ControlInterface` of your RDP client object:

```
Ircns5 := rdp1.ControlInterface as IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5;
if Assigned(Ircns5) then
  Ircns5.Set_AllowPromptingForCredentials(False);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the username and password to the Windows API function "[LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx)" before establishing the connection. For this to work the authenticating entity must be available on the user's network.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Windows;

var
    hToken : THandle;

begin
    if (ParamCount <> 3) then
    begin
        WriteLn ('LogonUserTest.exe [user name] [domain] [password]');
        Halt ($FF);
    end; { if }

    try
        Win32Check (LogonUser (PChar (ParamStr (1)), PChar (ParamStr (2)),
                               PChar (ParamStr (3)), Logon32_Logon_Interactive,
                               LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, hToken));
        WriteLn ('LogonUser success');
        CloseHandle (hToken);

    except
        on E: Exception do
            Writeln (E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end; { try / except }
end.
```

Comment: that is not what am looking for
but its useful for other things
thanks a lot :)